# Calling a parent method from a child class with a variable of that child

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, python-requests

Started working on my Python Keitaro Admin API library. There is a of couple targets I need to request to. Like offers, campaigns, streams or affiliate networks. They have similar request url, for example:

1. `https://example.com/v1/admin_api/offers` if I need to interact with offers
2. `https://example.com/v1/admin_api/campaigns` if I need to interact with campaigns
   and so on.

I want to interact with API in python code like this:
create like object Keitaro with class variables url and api_key. And keitaro methods like get and post. And then add variable 'target' to child classes so I can call Keitaro get/post methods with 'target' variable of offer or campaign.

Desired code pattern:

```
from keitaropy import Keitaro

app = Keitaro('https://example.com/', 'api_key')
offer_of_app = app.offer.get(123) # get by id
offers_of_app = app.offer.get() # get all

app2 = Keitaro('https://otherurl.com/', 'other_api_key')
offer_of_app2 = app2.offer.get(11)
offers_of_app2 = app2.offer.get()
```

Why I think this code snippet is better then code snippet from below: I don't need to import child classes like Offer, Streams, Campaigns. I can just import Keitaro class and use target variable of childs by calling that classes as method offer/campaign/stream as above.

What have I achieved:

```
from keitaropy import Offer

offer_app = Offer('https://example.com/', 'api_key')
offer = offer.get(123)
offers = offer.get()
```

Code of keitaropy:

```py
import requests
import json


def add_target_path(base_url, target, separator = '/'):
if base_url.endswith(separator):
    url = base_url + target
else:
    url = base_url + separator + target
return url

    
class Keitaro:
    def __init__(self, base_url, api_key, target):
        self.headers = { 'Api-Key': api_key }
        self.base_url = base_url
        self.target = target


    def get(self, target_id = None):
        url = add_target_path(self.base_url, self.target)
        if target_id:
            # get by id
            url = add_target_path(url, target_id)
        # if no id get all
        response = requests.get(url, headers=self.headers)
        return response.json()


    def post(self, data):
        pass


class Offer(Keitaro):
    def __init__(self, base_url, api_key):
        self.target = 'offers'
        super().__init__(base_url, api_key, self.target)


class Campaign(Keitaro):
    def __init__(self, base_url, api_key):
        self.target = 'campaigns'
        super().__init__(base_url, api_key, self.target)


class Stream(Keitaro):
    def __init__(self, base_url, api_key):
        self.target = 'streams'
        super().__init__(base_url, api_key, self.target)


class AffNetwork(Keitaro):
    def __init__(self, base_url, api_key):
        self.target = 'affiliate_networks'
        super().__init__(base_url, api_key, self.target)
```

I don't like the idea of storing child variable 'target' in parent class just for call parent method get but don't have any ideas to do it better way. If you have some ideas share with me please

Also childs Campaign, Offer and so on can have their own methods which is not inherent in the parent class.

Comment: Still would be good if there is any examples how can I achieve first code snippet!
So I can use parent attributes for multiple offers for example

Comment: added more details in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64026236/implementing-a-parent-method-call-as-a-child-method-with-its-own-attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question turned out to be more complex than I expected. Example of it you can check in my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Infvmous/keitaropy)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the parent class having an attribute like `target` which it uses directly. There is also nothing wrong with a child class setting the value:

```py
class Offer(Keitaro):
    def __init__(self, base_url, api_key):
        super().__init__(base_url, api_key, 'offers')
```

You have just gained a benefit that classes like `Offer` and `Campaign` have reduced the number of parameters needed to instantiate a class.

Comment: I think so but how can I change the code to call get method from parent class with child attribute (for example 'offers') like I mention in 'Desired code pattern' above. That's is the main question

Comment: Which `child attribute` are you referring to?

Comment: target = 'offers' for example
I want to pass it to parent class to call get method which is using parent attributes and want to call this method as in 'Desired code pattern' in question above

Comment: If your first code snippet is your `Desired code pattern` and your second is what you have achieved, I prefer your second. Much cleaner.

Comment: I want users to be able to create multiple applications Keitaro with different api_keys and urls. And use Offer/Campaign/AffNetwork/Streams attributes and methods

Comment: You have that now: `offer_app = Offer(...)` and `campaign_app = Campaign(...)` etc

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll continue to work on this library with this code pattern then. And will update the question if there any problems

Comment: Actually this should have been on CodeReview. Any data errors or error tracebacks and you should post here.

Comment: Also updated the first code snippet, maybe now it will be clearer what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid passing 'target' variable via constructor and instead call the parent get method directly from your preferred method in child while passing target as argument.